# How to Convert Bot Composer .DIALOG to AdaptiveDialog .CS using .NET SDK

Tags: c#, botframework, bot-framework-composer, adaptive-dialogs

I created a project using Bot Composer Tool and implemented many dialogs . In solution folder I can see all dialog files are JSON format with file format **.dialog**.

**Requirement:**

I had to create a same project using AdaptiveDialogs (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs) approach using .NET SDK .

I found below github link for same on how to develop a adaptivedialogs using .NET SDK.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/adaptive-dialog

I also found Bot Composer Samples

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/composer-samples

**But is there any tool that I convert Bot Composer ".dialog" file JSON to adaptive dialog .CS file that can compatible to AdaptiveDialog SDK Code.**

Comment: why you want convert to .cs file ? any specific reason

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way to convert a `.dialog` to the equivalent `.cs` file, although it'd be possible to implement one.

However, you can run a bot created with Composer in a custom runtime, where you can make certain customizations.

The custom runtime actually uses those `.dialog` files, so you don't need to convert to code to use Adaptive Dialogs.